# How to check whether rss feed provides older feeds or not?

Tags: rss

I've done some googling on the topic of getting older rss feeds and found clues that there's a possibility that rss feed provides such service.

Is there a way to determine whether the feed does provide older records or not?

Comment: No, there isn't.  There is no standard way of providing feeds, so any parameters you can throw at the script generating the feed are site-dependent.

Answer (score 2):

how about the ancient art of just *asking* the rss provider?

Comment: I've already done it, but sometimes it takes a whole month to get an answer from provider's support.